# How to block all IP from accessing a page on web site

Tags: htaccess

Is there a way to block all IP addresses except my own from a certain page on our website using `.htaccess`?

Comment: Please try php code in your pages <?php $blacklist = array("123.456.789", "456.789.123", "789.123.456");

if(in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $blacklist)) {

 header("Location: http://domain.tld/path/custom.php");

 exit();

} ?>

Answer (score 0):

Try Using this magento extension http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/et-ip-security.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<Files *>
Order Allow,Deny 
Allow from 123.123.123.123 (YOUR IP)
Deny from all 
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

Various iterations of doing this as noted.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uri-path/to/restricted/page.php [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^0\.0\.0\.0
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

Change URI path to page you want to limit access to and IP address to the source accessee. Commonly used to lock down Admin access with the following rule.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(index.php/)?admin(.*) [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^0\.0\.0\.0
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^0\.0\.0\.0
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

Duplicate IP rules line with as many ip addresses as you use and note that `\` is used to comment the `.` for regex match on the IP